# apt-key add with wget not working

Tags: apt, openvpn, wget

I am trying to make an openVpn from [How to Install OpenVPN on Ubuntu](https://tonyteaches.tech/openvpn-ubuntu/).

I have 2 unbuntu servers which I connect to them with putty from windows. both servers are `ubuntu-20.04-x86_64`. after executing `apt install ca-certificates wget net-tools gnupg` with no problem on both then execute `wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -` but on one of them the system just hangs without any error(`COM1`). the `wget -qO - https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as-repo-public.gpg | apt-key add -` executes on other server(`COM2`) without any problem so the lines works totally fine.

then I do `cat wget-log` it doesnt show anything.

#### update

I also tried to get the `wget part` from `COM2` and made a text file with `vim` with info in wget part with no extension then did `cat textfile | apt-key add -` this time it messaged `OK` but later running `apt install openvpn-as` it errored `can't locate openvpn-as`

What can I do about it?

Comment: You still need to run `apt-get update` for packages from a newly added repo to become available

Comment: https://tonyteaches.tech/openvpn-ubuntu/ has `apt update` after that